The Google Marketplace app isn’t showing up in the Drive "Open With" section
We’re working to publish an app to the Google Marketplace for our Drive API, but it's being rejected by Google's review team, who say they can't see the app in the "Open With" section.
Before submitting, we created a private app for testing purposes, where we only configured the "Default file extensions" under the "Drive UI Integration" section. This private app worked perfectly and appeared in the "Open With" section as expected.

However, when we submitted the public app with the exact same configurations, Google’s review team is rejecting it, stating that it still doesn’t appear in the "Open With" section. We understand that this visibility should be controlled by the "Default file extensions" settings, but while these settings work fine in the private app, they aren’t working the same way in the public app from the review team’s perspective.
I followed all the configuration steps according to Google’s documentation. Here is the scope I specified for the app:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file


Can you share which Google’s documentation you are referring to?

Hi @PatrickdC, here is the documentation link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-sdk
At point 9 you'll see, they mentioned "Enter default MIME types and file extensions"

Have you also read the succeeding article about Integrate with Drive UI's "Open with" context menu? Because if you say that you have already done the steps on the first article, then it might be possible that you missed something based on the succeeding article.

@PatrickdC yes, I received the rejection because the application does not appear in the "Open With" menu. I have already configured the "Default MIME Types" and "Default File Extensions" in the Google Drive API under the Drive UI Integration settings. Where else should I check?
